# File handle variable?

Tags: file, vb6

I get a bad record number error when I use this:

```
Put #filehandle, (i * 100) + x, buf(x)
```

when filehandle is an integer, that I opened via this.

```
filehandle = FreeFile
Open (App.Path & "\" & BufferFileRootName & "A") For Binary As filehandle
```

How could I fix this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: File numbers are not file handles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the values of `i` and `x` that you are using. A bad record number on `put` usually indicates that the record number is less than or equal to zero.

If you print out the values of `i` and `x` (as well as the result of that calculation), it should hopefully tell you what's wrong.

Keep in mind that record numbers are 1-based so, if both your `i` and `x` variables are zero, that would cause this problem.